# How to kill MySQL connections

Tags: mysql, connection

I'm building a website with MySQL.  I'm using TOAD for MySQL and suddenly I can't connect to the database as I'm getting an error:

> **"Too many connections"**

Is there any way in Toad for MySQL to view existing connections to be able to kill them or simple close all connections all together?

Comment: If you are running out of connections you probably are doing something wrong in your website, like not closing your connections properly.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

No, there is **no built-in MySQL command** for that. There are various tools and scripts that support it, you can kill some connections manually or restart the server (but that will be slower).

Use `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to view all connections, and `KILL` the process ID's you want to kill.

You could edit the timeout setting to have the MySQL daemon kill the inactive processes itself, or raise the connection count. You can even **limit the amount of connections per username**, so that if the process keeps misbehaving, the only affected process is the process itself and no other clients on your database get locked out.

If you can't connect yourself anymore to the server, you should know that MySQL always reserves 1 extra connection for a user with the **`SUPER` privilege**. Unless your offending process is for some reason using a username with that privilege...

Then after you can access your database again, you should fix the process (website) that's spawning that many connections.

Comment: Note, limit per username was introduced on 5.0.3, so if you're running 4.1 or something like that you are out of luck.

Answer (score 59):

```
mysql> SHOW PROCESSLIST;
+-----+------+-----------------+------+---------+------+-------+---------------+
| Id  | User | Host            | db   | Command | Time | State | Info      |
+-----+------+-----------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------+
| 143 | root | localhost:61179 | cds  | Query   |    0 | init  | SHOW PROCESSLIST |
| 192 | root | localhost:53793 | cds  | Sleep   |    4 |       | NULL      |
+-----+------+-----------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> KILL 192;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

**USER 192 :**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM exept;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM exept;
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Comment: `mysql> SELECT * FROM exept;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    804
Current database: xxx`

Answer (score 32):

While you can't kill all open connections with a single command, you can create a set of queries to do that for you if there are too many to do by hand.

This example will create a series of `KILL <pid>;` queries for all `some_user`'s connections from `192.168.1.1` to `my_db`.

```sql
SELECT 
CONCAT('KILL ', id, ';') 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST 
WHERE `User` = 'some_user' 
AND `Host` = '192.168.1.1'
AND `db` = 'my_db';
```

Comment: Getting `KILL <pid>` as output, how to execute the same there itself?

Comment: @Prem Depending on how you do your SQL queries Ctrl+C then ctrl+V should allow you to copy the output of the query, and paste it as a new query. You could also get tricky and pipe the output of the query into another mysql command, depending on your shell.

Answer (score 14):

I would recommend checking the connections to show the maximum thread connection is

```
show variables like "max_connections";
```

sample

```
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 13  |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set
```

Then increase it by example

```
set global max_connections = 500;
```

Comment: Cool, Thanks a lot,

Comment: Edit the file: /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf  Mysql install default:151 and Max Value:100.000 See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections

Answer (score 9):

In MySQL Workbench:

Left-hand side navigator > Management > Client Connections

It gives you the option to kill queries and connections.

*Note: this is not TOAD like the OP asked, but MySQL Workbench users like me may end up here*

Comment: Just a note: in Workbench 8.0, Management is a tab in the Navigator on the left. After opening that tab, Client Connections is an option under the Management header.

Answer (score 5):

As above mentioned, there is no special command to do it. However, if all those connection are  inactive, using 'flush tables;' is able to release all those connection which are not active.

Answer (score 1):

run this command on the selected DB

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('KILL ',id SEPARATOR '; ') AS kill_list

FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST

WHERE command='Sleep' AND DB IS NOT NULL;