# Drop user from MySQL doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I am trying to delete a user from MySQL server :

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=mysql;charset=utf8","$adminname", "$pass",array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
$sql_deleteuser="DELETE FROM `mysql`.`user` WHERE `user`.`User` = '$username'";                 
//$sql_deleteuser="SELECT `User` FROM `mysql`.`user`";  
$PDOStatement3=$conn->prepare($sql_deleteuser);
//$PDOStatement3->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$res_exec=$PDOStatement3->execute();
```

but it doesn't work and no error in `errorInfo()` , I tried

`$sql_deleteuser="DROP USER '$username'@'%'";`

and

`$sql_deleteuser="IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'$username') DROP USER [$username]";`  same result.

The connection was fine I test it with a `SELECT` query and it works.

Did I miss something. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need privileges to drop a user

Comment: Yes I have , the connection was already made with an admin account

Comment: you can check error by setting PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); by the way  $conn->exec($sql_deleteuser); should also work, no need to prepare!

Comment: `sys.database_principal` this is sql server change your tags

Comment: in fact it is a privilege issue as I get `Syntax error or access violation` , but I have `ALL PRIVILEGES` for the admin as  `SuperUser localhost  global ALL PRIVILEGES Yes ` for `user` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you have not the priviliges / rights to drop a user

> The DROP USER statement removes one or more MySQL accounts. 
>   To use it, you must have the DELETE privilege for the mysql database

**OR**

perhaps the problem is that the user has a open connection
because the mysql doc says:

> **Important**
>
> *DROP USER* does not automatically close any open user
>   sessions. Rather, in the event that a user with an open session is
>   dropped, the statement does not take effect until that user's session
>   is closed. Once the session is closed, the user is dropped, and that
>   user's next attempt to log in will fail. This is by design.

How to kill the connections see this answer:

[how to kill mySQL connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932503/how-to-kill-mysql-connections)

See DOC:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-user.html

Comment: Yes it is privileges issue, despite of having `ALL PRIVILEGES`  for `user` table the user admin cannot execute  `DELETE` or `DROP`

Comment: have you checked the open connections ?

Comment: Yes I didn't open any connection with the user target account, is there a way to force closing it ?

Comment: see my edit post and do you tried the droping with the root user or a use with only root like privileges? if second try it with the root user.

Comment: Yes it drop it with root user, how to make it with my admin user  he has the same privileges as the root !!!

Comment: As a  solution I revoked all privileges from my user instead of dropping it completely and tell the admin to drop it manually later if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//Edit: Use REVOKE to revoke the privileges. This removes rows for the account from all the grant tables except the user table, and revokes any global privileges listed in the user table.

// sql to delete a record, use $host to remove a specific user
$sql = "DELETE FROM `mysql`.`user` WHERE `user`.`User` = '$username" AND `user`.`Host` = '$host";


// use exec() because no results are returned
$conn->exec($sql);
echo "Record deleted successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
```

try with above code, you will find also out the error!

Comment: First, you're not escaping '$username'; second you should be dropping another user account and not the one you're using to connect to the db. Third, in the your exec call you're not checking the return value...and just assuming success.